# RecyclerView: inflate another line of LinearLayout in Adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater

I'm trying to inflate 2 lines of LinearLayout into my custom adapter when necessary. To avoid that my inflated LinearLayout gets cut off on the edge of my ListView, I want to limit my number of inflated images for each row to 5.

**BLOCKLAYOUT.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>
```

**BlockAdapter.java**

```
public BlockAdapter(Context context,List<Cscore> blocks, int pos) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.blocks = blocks;
        this.currentPosition = pos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public BlockAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.block_layout, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(blocks != null) {
            holder.bind(blocks.get(currentPosition),null);
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final List<ImageView> imageViews = new ArrayList<>();
        private final ViewGroup container;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            container = (ViewGroup) itemView;
        }

        public void bind(Cscore block) {
            recycleImageViews();
            if(block !=null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < block.getMaxscore(); ++i) {
                    final ImageView imageView = getRecycledImageViewOrCreate();
                    Picasso.get().load(block.getImgurl()).into(imageView);
                    imageViews.add(imageView);
                    container.addView(imageView);


                }
            }

        }

        private ImageView getRecycledImageViewOrCreate() {
            if (imageViewPool.isEmpty()) {
                return (ImageView)LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.imageView, container, false);
            }
            return imageViewPool.remove(0);
        }

        public void recycleImageViews() {
            imageViewPool.addAll(imageViews);
            imageViews.clear();
            container.removeAllViews();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        holder.recycleImageViews();
    }
}
```

This BlockAdapter only inflates images and is a child of another Adapter which displays text and other stuff. Therefor my getItemCount() returns 1, because I only want to have 1 RecyclerView do be displayed inside the parent Adapter.

R.layout.imageView is a simple imageView:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/block"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_l"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_l" />
```

I tried working on the bind method:

```
public void bind(Cscore block) {
recycleImageViews();
if(block !=null) { ...}  
imageViews.add(imageView);
container.addView(imageView);
}
```

there I should inflate another row / line of LinearLayout with horizontal orientation when reaching the 5th item in my ImagesList... proceeding obviously with the 6th item and not with the 1st